# Distributedly "dumping"/"compressing" data samples

Tags: java, math, audio, signal-processing

I'm not really sure what's the right title for my question
So here's the question
Suppose I have N number of samples, eg:
1
2
3
4
.
.
.
N

Now I want to "reduce" the size of the sample from N to M, by dumping (N-M) data from the N samples. 
I want the dumping to be as "distributed" as possible,
so like if I have 100 samples and want to compress it to 50 samples, I would throw away every other sample. Another example, say the data is 100 samples and I want to compress it to 25 samples. I would throw away 1 sample in the each group of 100/25 samples, meaning I iterate through each sample and count, and every time my count reaches 4 I would throw away the sample and restart the count.
The problem is how do I do this if the 4 above was to be 2.333 for example. How do I treat the decimal point to throw away the sample distributively?

Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms you are looking for are [resampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28audio%29), [downsampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downsampling) and [decimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_%28signal_processing%29). Note that in the general case you can't just throw away a subset of your data without risking [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). You need to [low pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_pass_filter) your data first, prior to decimation, so that there is no information above your new [Nyquist rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate) which would be aliased.

When you want to downsample by a non-integer value, e.g. 2.333 as per your example above you would normally do this by upsampling by an integer factor M and then downsampling by a different integer factor N, where the fraction `M/N` gives you the required resampling factor. In your example `M = 3` and `N = 7`, so you would upsample by a factor of 3 and then downsample by a factor of 7.

Answer (score 0):

1. You seem to be talking about sampling rates and digital signal processing
2. Before you reduce, you normally filter the data to make sure high frequencies in your sample are not aliased to lower frequencies.  For instance, in your (take every fourth value), a frequency of that repeats every four samples will alias to the "DC" or zero cycle frequency (for example "234123412341" starting with the first of every grouping  will get "2,2,2,2", which might not be what you want.  (a 3 cycle would also alias to a cycle like itself (231231231231) => 231... (unless I did that wrong because I'm tired).  Filtering is a little beyond what I would like to discuss right now as it's a pretty advanced topic.
3. If you can represent your "2.333" as some sort of fraction, lets see, that's 7/3.  you were talking 1 out of every 4 samples (1/4) sou I would say you're taking 3 out of every 7 samples.  so you might  (take, drop, take, drop, take, drop, drop).  but there might be other methods.

Answer (score 0):

For audio data that you want to sound decent (as opposed to aliased and distorted in the frequency domain), see Paul R.'s answer involving resampling.  One method of resampling is interpolation, such as using a windowed-Sinc interpolation kernel which will properly low-pass filter the data as well as allow creating interpolated intermediate values.

For non-sampled and non-audio data, where you just want to throw away some samples in a close-to-evenly distributed manner, and don't care about adding frequency domain noise and distortion, something like this might work:

```
float myRatio = (float)(N-1) / (float)(M-1);  // check to make sure M > 1 beforehand
for (int i=0; i < M; i++) {
  int j = (int)roundf(myRatio * (float)i);  // nearest bin decimation
  myNewArrayLengthM[i] = myOldArrayLengthN[j];
}
```